# Applying for a visa for a conference visit to US but flying to a different city at first

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

I have purchased a flight ticket to Atlanta (from Europe). However, I will apply for the visa for participating a conference in Texas. I just want to spend 1-2 days in Atlanta with old friends (then travel to Texas for the conference). I wonder if this would be an issue when I apply for visa (which should be B1/B2 type) or it would be an issue when I enter US in Atlanta airport. I will also buy tickets from Atlanta to Texas, if this would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't even need to mention Atlanta at the visa interview at the embassy (because you're not expected to present your flight tickets).

At Atlanta, just tell the CBP what you wrote here, and you should be completely fine. Your situation is very normal.

Comment: thank you sir! :) I will tell the CBP that I have a meeting with the professor who was my PhD supervisor!